# Shiny - filtering for user input variable

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm just trying to create a basic shiny app that allows the user to view simple plots for a selected variable and apply filters as required.

However, I am having difficulty getting the plot to work with the filters applied. I can get the plot to work if I don't apply the filters, but the current code gives the error: "Error: no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "character"".

I realise the problem is to do with what is trying to be plotted and probably something to do with the filter applied to "input$Variable", but I cannot work it out! Any help appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
data <- read.csv("df1Final.csv", stringsAsFactors = T)

ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("PhD Data"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        uiOutput("Variable"), 
        sliderInput("Age.Yr", "Age:", 8, 12, c(8,12), step = 0.25),
         sliderInput("Train.Hr", "Training (Hours):", 9, 11, c(9,11), step = 0.1),
         sliderInput("Grade", "Grade:", 3, 5, c(3,5), step = 1)
      ),
      mainPanel(plotOutput("coolplot"),
                br(), br(),
                verbatimTextOutput("results")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$Variable <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Variable", "Data:", choices = colnames(data)[-1])
  })

  filtered <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$Variable)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    input$Variable %>%
      filter(Age.Yr >= input$Age.Yr[1],
             Age.Yr <= input$Age.Yr[2],
             Train.Hr >= input$Train.Hr[1],
             Train.Hr <= input$Train.Hr[2],
             Grade >= input$Grade[1],
             Grade <= input$Grade[2] 
      )
  })

  output$coolplot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(filtered())) {
      return()
    }

    ggplot(filtered(), aes(x=filtered(), color=Group)) +
      geom_density()
  })
  output$results <- renderPrint({
    describeBy(data[,input$Variable], data$Group, mat = F)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try as.numeric like as.numeric(input$Age.Yr[1]) and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have been able to get this to work by adjusting the filtering to be:

```
data[input$Variable] %>% ...
```

I then had to also adjust the aes in ggplot to be:

```
aes_string(x=input$Variable)
```

Still trying to work out how to add the color = Group to the ggplot at the moment as this now doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are filtering on the actual value that Shiny passes you and not on your data. Input$Variable is not a set of data, it is just the title of that column of data.

Try printing out input$Variable before acting on it.

Comment: Is this what you mean? I tried doing this: plotdata <- reactive({as.data.frame(input$Variable)})
Then I tried using the plotdata() in the filtered section (instead of input$Variable) but now get an error saying "Result must have length 1, not 105".

Comment: So I have worked out that input$Variable was just returning the name of the variable, hence why I was having problems. I had to have data[input$Variable] for the data filtering. Now just having problems with the actual aes for ggplot!